# Perfmon showing 2.1 billion Instances of my WCF service

Tags: wcf, instance

I've a WCF service that only about 15-20 clients are calling once every three minutes. I have PerfMon hooked up to it, and it's showing that I have 2147483698 Instances. That can't be, can it? I have `maxConcurrentInstances="1000"` in the web.config and I'm using Multiple and PerSession Concurrency and InstanceMode respectively.
This WCF service is also causing some other problems like making lsass.exe use all the available CPU.

**Edit More Info**
It is hosted in IIS 6 and is using an endpoint with WsHttpBinding:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSHttpBinding_IWCFService" 
        maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="1048576">
    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="65536" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
            algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
   </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

I have the Concurrency set to Multiple to because I want the Service Objects that are created to be able to handle more than one request at a time (ie multiple threads). I suppose I could make the InstanceMode Single, instead of PerSession, but would that make a difference here?

**Edit Next Morning**
So, I got on this morning and opened PerfMon, everything was flatlined at 0. I removed then created the the service in IIS, and also restarted the service by modifying the config. I then watched the Instances climb up to 1000 (the max in my config), at which point no more calls were coming in. I restarted the service again using the config, the number of Instances immediately dropped to 0, then 5 seconds later shot up to 2 billion again.
I feel like part of this might just be that Perfmon doesn't know how to handle whatever madness is being thrown at it from the WCF service.

The problem does seem to be that the channel is not always being closed properly in this particular version of the client and unfortunately, I can't get to them all at the moment. (I have another version of the client and service that has about 130 clients and this isn't a problem.) Is there some configuration I could set the service up as to help the problem? From what I've read, Single InstanceMode and Multiple Concurrency would be appropriate. It would solve the Instance problem and still give me asynchronous access, and I don't have to worry about cross threading issues because the service methods only update tables in a DB.
Thoughts?

Comment: Does your service serve up free money?

Comment: Can you provide some more information, such as what you're hosting with (IIS, Windows Service, etc), bindings?  Also, I'm curious as to why you have InstanceMode set to Multiple?

Comment: Hmmm.....Rather than switching the InstanceMode to Single, I'd try and reduce the number of clients and/or the frequency of the connections first, to see if that has any affect.  Also, are the clients properly closing the communication channel when they are done?  (You may not know the answer if the clients aren't under your control).

Comment: This number of instances seems wrong - it's 2G (+50), so only with instances of your service you should have > 8GB of memory used by the process (I'd guess the minimum memory for an object would be a 4-byte pointer). You can try logging any time a new instance is created in a file or some other place to validate that the number of intances that you get is correct.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the instances are not being disposed of correctly.

As a test you could append the following line of code to the implementation (in the service) of the method(s) being called by the clients, and see if the number of instances reduces:

```
 OperationContext.Current.InstanceContext.
        ReleaseServiceInstance();
```

You could also try switching to per-call and get rid of the concurrency stuff (I can't tell from your question if that option would be suitable for what you are doing)? Per call will create a separate instance for every method call that a client makes, and dispose of the instance afterwards.

There is a nice article that goes into all the details of instance management [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163590.aspx#S8), hopefully you will find something helpful there :)

Comment: Does the WCF service not close the Instance by itself? Or are we using that line of code to explicitly close it and avoid any chance that it might not be closed?  Thanks for the link, It'll take a while to read the whole thing.

Comment: Yes, it should in theory happen automatically at some point (the when and how of this depends on how it has been configured), the line of code is just a test to help narrow down where the problem is. Good Luck, and if you find anything pls post it for us curious people :)

Comment: 's comments and the article linked to above give you another option: Decorate your service operations with the ReleaseInstanceMode.BeforeCall attribute (other options are None, AfterCall and BeforeAndAfterCall. Based on what you've added above, I recommend BeforeCall so it clean up any resources and kill any sessions that were not properly closed by the client.